How to programatically "disable or disconnect" RF antenna
I have a setup of TinySA Ultra and logoperiodic antenna connected to it. There are cases when TinySA could be near powerful signal source (up to 30W). Such signal will damage TinySA, and to prevent that I thought of somehow disconnect antenna (I cannot simply turn TinySA off, because signal will still be captured and will destroy build in LNA in TinySA).
My idea was to use either RF switch and switch between connected antenna and other free SMA port, or to use power limitter and do not pass strong signals to TinySA. But I'm afraid that by doing that I will damage RF switch or limitter.
Question is: how to block such powerful signals, and is RF switch or power limitter a solution here? Will appreciate any help!
I'm RF beginner so feel free to correct my question.

What are you using the antenna for? Maybe reveal your circuit?

there's no circuit. antenna connected directly to TinySA via SMA connector. I want to put something between them to block or remove powerful signal

Find or build an attenuator

Protecting a receiver against too strong rf signals is common. At best it's done in the design phase of the receiver. Inserting a protector to the already built receiver input circuit can be simple at low frequencies, but at microwaves one must add a limiter block between the antenna and the receiver. You can find such devices easily by making a web search rf power limiter. But know that the quality and price vary widely. You may find low cost devices from Amazon or other marketplaces, but only testing reveals how they perform - I mean do they attenuate enough too strong signals and allow weak ones to pass without too much attenuation when the high power signal is off.
Of course, for those who accept only the best and do not at first ask the price there's also numerous options available. But they can cost 100 times as much as low cost Neverheardbefore branded or nameless products.
Hopefully your computer is well protected against external rf fields and doesn't crash near the transmitter.
